# copy/paste text use pdf-tools in emacs

Tags: copy-paste, pdf-tools

when I use pdf-tools

the text in it can't be copy/paste as normal

I want to treat this pdf mode as a place where I get the information to use in emacs

Comment: When I mark a region using the mouse and then press `M-w` the marked region is in the kill-ring, i.e. I can paste it using `C-y`. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: the `M-w` and `C-y` can't be used between pdf-tools and emacs, so I give this issue

Comment: `M-w` and `C-y` do work in my case out of the box thanks to remapping in `pdf-view.el` which is part of `pdf-tools`. Search for `pdf-view-kill-ring-save` in that file and you will find the function itself and two key-remappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `pdf-view-kill-ring-save` to send highlighted text to the kill-ring. At that point you can yank it to a buffer as normal.